# Android Retain JS Variables in Webview Orientation Change

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have a webview and I load some html5+js into it. My webapp is extremely data intensive. Using the state functions, I am able to get back to the correct 'page' I am supposed to be on after orientation change, however my webapp is in peril because all my javascript variables have been reset as well.

Is there a method to have all my javascript variables saved and restored on webview orientation changes? What about values entered into form text boxes?

==================

I've made some progress on this. In my JS, I have a hook that is called `requestState();` When this function is called, it sends all my JS variables to the android / java side via JS Interface.

On the Java side I persist this information using `getLastNonConfigurationInstance` and `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`. I've tested the output and it does indeed save all my JS variables into my object in Java right before the activity state is changed on orientation alterations.

The issue is getting back to where I am supposed to be. I have a function in my JS which functions the opposite of `requestState();` called `setState(input);`. This function is invoked from the Android side by using `mywebview.loadUrl( "javascript:setState(" + jsonStr + ")" );`. I do this at the end of my onCreate, after deflating the webview and calling `wv.restoreState(savedInstanceState);`.

What I have noticed though is that `setState` has not been defined at the time of me calling it! In fact, none of my JS scripts are ready to be called or even exist / are found at the end of my activity's onCreate function. To test my sanity, I tried `mywebview.loadUrl( "javascript:alert(" + jsonStr + ")" );` and I indeed saw what I expected to see -- the alert with all my variable values in it. However I noticed that the page itself hadn't rendered before the alert came up. How should I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't waste your time guys. After much peril, I've decided to go with html5 local storage, which I guess most people must use anyway since there is no resolution to the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I can think of is to reload the WebView using loadDataWithBaseURL, and pass it a preprocessed version of the contents of the page, inserting a custom body.onload handler which reinitializes all the necessary variables.

That is, once you see the <BODY sequence, prepend a <SCRIPT> ... </SCRIPT> part containing a definition of a function that does the necessary setup, and then inject an ONLOAD attribute into the <BODY ...> tag to call this function.

Of course, if there is already a <BODY ONLOAD...>, then things get slightly more complicated. But only slightly...